# A particles motion is described, find the average velocity in the third second

Tags: calculus, derivatives

> A particles motion is described by $x(t) = 4t^3 - 5t^2$. Find the average velocity in the third second.

So I found the derivative

> $12t^2 - 10t$

Then I plugged in $3$ for time and got $78$, but the answer is $51$. I don't think I fully understand what the question is asking. Thanks for any help. I appreciate it.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig sorry that was a typo thanks for the catch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first second is from time $t=0$ to time $t=1$.  The second second ends at $t=2$.  The third second starts at time $t = 2$ and ends at time $t = 3$.  You found an instantaneous velocity (instantaneous rate of change).  You did not find an average velocity (average rate of change).  How much did the position change between $t = 2$ and $t = 3$ (without inspecting the position at any other time)?  How much time elapsed between $t = 2$ and $t = 3$?  Can you find the average rate of change from these two differences?

Answer (score 1):

So your position is governed by $$x(t) = 4t^3-5t^2$$ and hence the velocity is given by $$v(t) = x'(t) = 12t^2-10t.$$

*In the third second*, in other words, between $t=2$ and $t=3$, velocity is changing. You need to find the average value of the velocity in $t \in (2,3)$.

---

Now that Eric's answer has been posted and accepted, I can add where it comes from. Generally you would have to compute
$$
\frac{1}{3-2} \int_{t=2}^{t=3} v(t) dt
 = \frac{1}{3-2} \int_2^3 x'(t) dt
 = \frac{x(3)-x(2)}{3-2}.
$$